# Error creating Terrain in HEC-RAS

Tags: grass-gis, hec-ras

I am struggling to produce a terrian file with RAS Mapper.

I have a .tif file produced from a .asc raster elevation and when I tried to add a *New Terrain Model* as described in the documentation I get the following error:

> Error creating Terrain: Input string was not in a correct format.

[image]

I have gone through all options related with the file paths and it seems to be something with the file itself, but what?

Among the many ways I have tried to produce it I am using GRASS.

The source of the raster data:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      DTM2plus_2-18882@MA            Date: Mon May 28 12:04:37 2018    |
 | Mapset:   MA                             Login of Creator: MA              |
 | Location: GRASS_SWEREF99_1800                                              |
 | DataBase: R:\6_GIS\62_A_Data\                                              |
 | Title:    DTM2plus_2-18882                                                 |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    FCELL                                                      |
 |   Rows:         2500                                                       |
 |   Columns:      2500                                                       |
 |   Total Cells:  6250000                                                    |
 |        Projection: SWEREF99 18 00                                          |
 |            N:    6647500    S:    6642500   Res:     2                     |
 |            E:     185000    W:     180000   Res:     2                     |
 |   Range of data:    min = 8.68  max = 39.2                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by r.patch                                                    |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    r.patch input="x800_664_18_5025@MA,x800_664_18_5000@MA\                 |
 |    ,x800_664_18_2525@MA,x800_664_18_2500@MA" output="DTM2\                 |
 |    plus_2-18882"                                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The command to produce the tif file:

```
r.out.gdal input=DTM2plus_2-18882@MA output=R:\6_GIS\DTM2plus_2-1882B.tif format=GTiff
```

Comment: Try to change the minus '-' in your output raster name to underscore: "_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the 32 bits of the image by default that had to be set to 64 bits:

```
r.out.gdal input=DTM2plus_2-18882@MA output=R:\6_GIS\62_A_Data\DTM2plus_2-1882C.tif format=GTiff type=Float64 nodata=-9999
```